# Variables and functions in all parts of a makefile are expanded when read

Tags: c, makefile

In a `GNU make` tutorial said that:

> Variables and functions in all parts of a makefile are expanded when
>   read, except for in recipes, the right-hand sides of variable
>   definitions using ‘=’, and the bodies of variable definitions using
>   the define directive.

I'm written the following make:

```
CC:=gcc
$(CC)G=-o
TARGET=fmake
fmake: $(TARGET).c
    $(CC) $(gccG) $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c
```

and it's correctly compile my `.c` source file although I'm using varibale in the right-hand sides of variable definitions using ‘=’ and in recipe.

Comment: So the question is what, exactly?  If the question is "when are the variables expanded", that would be "when it comes time to actually execute the command to compile".

Comment: Does you mean that the variables expanded after the make shell command only in my case?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Where are you using a variable in the right-hand side of a variable definition using `=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it would be easier to explain what happens if you swap the order of the first two lines:

```
$(CC)G=-o
CC:=gcc
```

In the first line, the variable $(CC) appears on the *left* side, so it is expanded *right now when it is read*; but you haven't defined the variable yet, so it expands to a blank, and the end result would be as if you had typed `G=-o`.  Then when it comes time to expand `$(gccG)` there is no variable of that name so that also turns into a blank; so the actual command that is executed is `gcc  fmake fmake.c` (note the absence of a flag).

What this delayed expansion means is that something like this:

```
VAR=$(VAR2)
```

won't expand $(VAR2) right when it is read; what is stored is `$(VAR2)`.  VAR2 can be changed later, and then when VAR is expanded, it expands to $(VAR2), which is itself expanded to its new value.